# AWS Lambda with Python: "Unable to import module 'api.main': cannot import name 'is_unprintabl

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am trying to deply a python lambda code, and I get errors about packages I never heard before. Perhaps it something with the architecture?

directory structure

- scripts/package.sh
- api/main
- core # contains utils
- requirements.txt

how code is packaged

```
echo "Build Lambda :: Initializing virtual environment..."
rm -r env
python3.9 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate

echo "Build Lambda :: Installing dependencies..."
python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3.9 -m pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt

echo "Build Lambda :: Building lambda package..."
cd env/lib/python3.9/site-packages
zip -r9 ../../../../function.zip .
cd ../../../../
zip -g ./function.zip -r api
zip -g ./function.zip -r core
zip -g ./function.zip .env

echo "Build Lambda :: Done."
```

requirements.txt

```
aiohttp==3.8.1
bs4==0.0.1
black==22.3.0
emoji==0.6.0
fastapi==0.88.0
mangum==0.14.0
numpy==1.22.3
pydantic==1.9.1
pymongo==4.1.1
pytz==2021.3
uvicorn==0.15.0
python-dotenv==1.0.0
google-api-python-client==2.81.0
openai==0.27.2
nest-asyncio==1.5.6
regex==2022.9.13
requests==2.26.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
```

Here is the error:

```json
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'api.main': cannot import name 'is_unprintable' from 'charset_normalizer.utils' (/var/task/charset_normalizer/utils.py)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "6dfc12d9-6b17-40a0-a945-f81725e0099f",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: USE DOCKER!

To whom it may concern, this seems that this was a an architecture difference issue. I package my code inside a docker container with this image

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

...
```

Then I copied the zip from inside the container to outside the docker